# Heroku won't detect my Procfile from my Github repository?

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, discord.js

I'm trying to host a Discord bot on Heroku, and I've written all of my bot, but it won't detect my Procfile. I put it in the root directory of the repository, it's just Procfile with a capital P without a file extension, and I have no idea why it won't work. I've remembered to commit it and deploy my heroku project.

My Procfile:

[image: My Procfile]

The build log:

[image: Build log]

Comment: Your output says "Procfile declares types -> worker", which clearly indicates it's reading the Procfile just fine.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go to the build packs on Heroku and add node.js? If not that could be the problem. Also make sure to change the starter on Heroku.